# Looking for a library that can draw points on a vector and highlight connected points

Tags: web-apps, web

I'm looking for a web app library that can:

- Draw vector coordinates and give them the properties "catagory, name, and misc"
- When clicked, display these properties and highlight other coordinates with the same catagory

Something like this (excuse the MS paint):
[image: When P1 is clicked, it highlights P4 & P5 as they are part of the same catagory "Net A"]

When P1 is clicked, it highlights P4 & P5 as they are part of the same catagory "Net A"

[image: When P3 is clicked, it highlights P2 because they are both "Net B"]

When P3 is clicked, it highlights P2 because they are both "Net B"